# I clicked Abort during the installation of phpMyAdmin

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, ubuntu-16.04

I used the command:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
```

to install phpMyAdmin. During the installation, it said something like:

> your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements.

I clicked abort, and now when I try to install phpMyAdmin again using the same command above, the output is:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done php-gettext is already the newest version
>   (1.0.11-2build1). php-mbstring is already the newest version
>   (1:7.0+35ubuntu6). phpmyadmin is already the newest version
>   (4:4.5.4.1-2ubuntu2). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and
>   254 not upgraded.

I don't think it is letting me install phpMyAdmin again. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get remove --purge phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext && sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext`

Also [check out this guide for installing phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 14.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin), it may come in handy.

Comment: Thanks. Also, do you know how to solve the problem when you get this error message during the phpMyAdmin installation? An error occurred while installing the database:
mysql said: mysql: [Warning] mysql: Empty value for 'port' specified. Will throw an error in future versions ERROR 1819 (HY000) at line 1: Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements . Your options are: * abort - Causes the operation to fail; you will need to downgrade, reinstall, reconfigure this package, or otherwise manually intervene to continue using it. This will usually also impact your ability to inst